# Populating a combobox with List<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

After a combobox index changes, another combobox has to be populated with `List<string>` values. How am I able to do this?

For example:

Form (This is the way I'm having it now, incorrect though):

```
private void cbSelectEditFunction_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbSelectEditName.Items.Add(emp.FindEmployeeinFunction(cbSelectEditFunction.Text));    
}
```

Class method:

```
public List<string> FindEmployeeinFunction(string aFunction)
{
    List<string> EmployeeListFunction = new List<string>();

    foreach (Employee TempEmployee in EmployeeList)
    {
        if(TempEmployee.Function == aFunction)
        {
            EmployeeListFunction.Add(TempEmployee.Username);
        }
    }
    return EmployeeListFunction;
}
```

Hope it's understandable this way. Let me know if I've forgotten something!

Comment: Is it possible that the items.add method can only add one? This would mean that your list method would have to be called into a variable that is then looped through in order to add each option individually.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I was just making a local List<string> putting all the items in there. Then use Foreach to add the items to the combobox. I suppose there should be a better option. That one had me thinking though hehe! ;) Appreciate the thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `AddRange` is the method you're looking for

```
//Assuming you don't want to continually add new items use Clear()
cbSelectEditName.Items.Clear();

//Use AddRange to add the list.  ToArray() is used to convert List<> to string[]
cbSelectEditName.Items.AddRange(emp.FindEmployeeinFunction(cbSelectEditFunction.Text).ToArray());
```

Comment: It's not possible for me (yet) to actually use AddRange. AddRange wants an object[], I'm not having an object[]. I'm having a List<string>. Is there something I have to change in order to reach AddRange with my current situation?

Comment: Ahh, yes.  I've modified my example to include `.ToArray()` which will convert it to `string[]` which is a `object[]` (so it works)

Comment: Certainly, it does! You helped me a bunch! Thanks mate! :)